# Link multiple Datagridviews in one form C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have created a form in c# which contains three datagridviews from three sql tables. One field is common for all gridviews. If i select a checkbox in a gridview automatically other gridview check box columns should be selected where the common field value is equal. First grid view contains itmcod, title, procod, typcod these four fields. second one contains title,procod,defalt and the third one contains title,typcod,defalt, procod, title2. The value procod is common for all three datable. I i select a row in gridview 2 automatically gridview 1 & 3 should select all values where procod value is equal. How can i do this

Comment: What did you try? Hint: Look into SelectionChanged for the right event and into the various SelectedXXX properties!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like only whole rows to be selected, then I suggest you to set `.SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect` and `MultiSelect` to false, if you want to focus on only one row at a time. Then, you can achieve what you want like that in the SelectionChanged event of your first datagridview:

```
void DataGridView1SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If MultiSelect = true
        //foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        //If multiselect = false
        using(DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow)
        {
            foreach(DataGridViewRow rs in dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Concat(dataGridView3.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()).Where(r => !r.IsNewRow).Where(r => r.Cells["procod"].Value.ToString().Trim() != String.Empty).Where(r => r.Cells["procod"].Value.ToString() == row.Cells["procod"].Value.ToString()))
                rs.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

This just loops the rows in the other two datagridviews, that have the same value of the cell in the "procod" column.

Comment: its great its working i need to change this code bcoz i am selecting a checkbox in datagridview so other process should select the rows in other datagridviews with checkbox selected. I am new to to c# so can u pls help me to do this

Comment: I won't be on my PC for a couple of days, so I can only give you instructions: if your code is selecting the rows only when the checkbox is clciked, then you shouls just change the code in the body of the foreach loop. What you want to do is to find which of the columns on the row has datatype of type bool and set the value to that cell to true. You can use `IndexOf` on `rs.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()` and if the index is not -1, just set the value of the cell with that index to true. :)

Comment: this code is selecting the lines in other grid views where "procod" value is equal. if we unselect a line then already selected lines should be unselected. how can i do this with this code

Comment: Just add `.ClearSelection` for bot grid views at the beginning of the SelectionChanged event.